# Set one feature as linear and others as polynomial in Sklearn regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am doing linear regressions on Python with sklearn. I have plots of land on an area, have price, sq m, and distance to the sea.

I want to make the model in such a way that it takes sq m feature as linear, but distance to sea polynomial.

I have seen tutorials for polynomials, but are not multivariate and not for my case, 1 variable linear and other polynomial.

Can this be done? I am trying to predict land price and to plot that if possible, I am plotting what I have right now but "sq m" and "distance_sea" features are lineal.

**EDIT**

Here is a sample of the data:

```
area;sea_distance;price
547;144;399000
501;166;330000
525;166;330000
544;208;90000
502;208;140000
550;215;160000
519;230;130000
516;231;140000
518;231;140000
522;245;260000
552;245;500000
502;252;140000
544;252;140000
502;252;190000
550;255;230000
520;268;134000
472;277;250000
516;298;140000
591;388;75000
600;435;120000
476;445;55000
501;445;55000
501;445;55000
501;445;70000
520;513;175000
520;513;175000
501;520;55000
500;527;52000
511;533;95000
501;553;55000
511;553;55000
512;553;55000
500;562;160000
504;581;175000
724;581;175000
501;596;55000
500;600;50000
606;632;175000
526;633;50000
548;633;55000
300;698;25600
```

Some of the data don't fit perfectly, there are other variables that I don't have, for example some plot of land might have more elevation than other so the price is higher.

[image: plotted data]

This is the graph that I am getting out of that data, you see that distance to the sea is not lineal

Comment: Read 1.1.16 portion of this link: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html

Comment: Can you give a sample of your data ?

Comment: I have added sample data

Comment: @AlvaroHernandorena so you wnat the first column to be linear and rest all polynomial, right ?

Comment: Well "price" is Y and area is X1 and distance_sea is X2, I think the only one polynomial is distance_sea.